# Showing $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Let $f: U \to \Bbb{R}^m$ such that $U \subsetneq \Bbb{R}^2$ is open and $f \in \mathcal{C}^2$. Then $$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}.$$

Proof: Assume $f \in \mathcal{C}^2$, $U \subsetneq \Bbb{R}^2$, and $f: U \to \Bbb{R}^m$.
Thus, for all $a \in U$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a)\right)$ exists and they are continuous. We use the limit definition of partial derivatives to prove the identity.
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a) \right)
& = \lim_\limits{k \to 0}\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a_1, a_2 + k) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a_1, a_2)}{k} \\
&= \lim_\limits{k \to 0}\frac{1}{k} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a_1, a_2 + k) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a_1, a_2) \right) \\
& = \lim_\limits{k \to 0}\frac{1}{k} \left( \lim_\limits{h \to 0} \frac{f(a_1 + h, a_2 + k) - f(a_1, a_2 + k)}{h}\right) - \lim_\limits{k \to 0}\left( \frac{f(a_1 + h, a_2) - f(a_1, a_2)}{h} \right) \\
&= \lim_\limits{k \to 0} \frac{1}{k} \left(\lim_\limits{h \to 0} \frac{f(a_1 + h, a_2 + k) - f(a_1, a_2 + k) - f(a_1 + h, a_2) + f(a_1, a_2)}{h} \right)\\
&= \lim_\limits{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \left( \lim_\limits{k \to 0} \frac{f(a_1 + h, a_2 + k) - f(a_1 + h, a_2) - f(a_1, a_2 + k) + f(a_1, a_2)}{k}  \right) \\
& = \lim_\limits{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \left( \lim_\limits{k \to 0} \frac{f(a_1 + h, a_2 + k) - f(a_1 + h, a_2) - (f(a_1, a_2 + k) - f(a_1, a_2))}{k}  \right) \\
&= \lim_\limits{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a_1+h, a_2) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a_1, a_2) \right) \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a) \right)
\end{align}

Comment: I believe your textbook contains a proof to check, doesn't it?

Comment: where did you use the assumption that $f$ is $C^2$? Also, how do you justify the 5th equal sign (the interchange of limits)? That's exactly where the difficulty lies.

Comment: @VIVID: textbook has a different approach.

Comment: @peek-a-boo: May I justify it by saying that $h$ and $k$ are limits for the first and second coordinates, respectively, and so their independence from each other allows for the switching of limits?

Comment: $f \in \mathcal{C}^2$ implies that the second-order partial derivatives $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}(a)$ and  $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}(a)$ exist, for all $a \in U$, i.e. the given limits exist. Hence, the first and last equality.

Comment: No that's not a good reason. All you've used in this (erroneous proof) is the existence of the partials. You must invoke continuity at some point (strictly speaking continuity of partials is not needed, all you need is twice Frechet differentiability at a point). A correct proof is necessarily more elaborate. Just reiterating the cookie-cutter advice: ALWAYS ALWAYS be careful in analysis when interchanging limiting operations. These are always the trickiest issues, and if you erroneously interchange them, you'll end up with nonsense usually.

Comment: @peek-a-boo: Thanks for your feedback, and I guess I'll settle for the proof offered in the textbook. I hope you would not mind helping me understand why the switching of limits is invalid in my use case. Thanks again.

Comment: See [Interchange of Limiting Operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interchange_of_limiting_operations). There, you have an example of a double sequence which gives different answers when the limits are taken differently. You ask me "...understand why the switching of limits is invalid in my use case". Well, I never said in your case it is invalid, just that in your proof you never gave any explanation. So the burden is on you to explain why you can interchange limits in this case (and I'm sure your textbook must have given an explanation, and somewhere the proof uses continuity).